# SQL row total issue

Tags: sql

I have written a SQL query where it shows how many times product number 20 has been sold between 2019-12-01 and 2019-12-31 right now the output is

```
aantal:
2
1
```

but I want my output to be like:

```
aantal
3
```

instead of SQL showing up everything apart i want it to count everything from product number 20 and show 1 output '3' instead of 1, 2.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT aantal
FROM aankoop, transactie 
WHERE datum BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
  AND filiaalnummer = 35 
  AND product = 20
```

[SQL image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51AAO.png)

```
my sql query tables:



CREATE TABLE Bonuskaart (bonuskaartnummer SERIAL NOT NULL, naam varchar(255), adres varchar(255), woonpaats varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (bonuskaartnummer));
CREATE TABLE Transactie (transactienummer SERIAL NOT NULL, datum date NOT NULL, tijd time NOT NULL, bonuskaartnummer int4 NOT NULL, filiaalnummer int4 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (transactienummer));
CREATE TABLE Aankoop (transactienummer int4 NOT NULL, product int4 NOT NULL, aantal int4 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (transactienummer, product));
CREATE TABLE Filiaal (filiaalnummer SERIAL NOT NULL, plaats varchar(255) NOT NULL, adres varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (filiaalnummer));
CREATE TABLE Product (productnummer SERIAL NOT NULL, omschrijving varchar(255) NOT NULL, prijs numeric(6, 2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (productnummer));
ALTER TABLE Transactie ADD CONSTRAINT FKTransactie539737 FOREIGN KEY (bonuskaartnummer) REFERENCES Bonuskaart (bonuskaartnummer);
ALTER TABLE Transactie ADD CONSTRAINT FKTransactie8060 FOREIGN KEY (filiaalnummer) REFERENCES Filiaal (filiaalnummer);
ALTER TABLE Aankoop ADD CONSTRAINT FKAankoop632754 FOREIGN KEY (transactienummer) REFERENCES Transactie (transactienummer);
ALTER TABLE Aankoop ADD CONSTRAINT FKAankoop27756 FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES Product (productnummer);
```

and my sql query

```
ALTER TABLE bonuskaart ALTER COLUMN naam SET DEFAULT '(anoniem)';
INSERT INTO bonuskaart VALUES(65472335);
INSERT INTO filiaal VALUES(35,'Utrecht','Stationsplein');
INSERT INTO filiaal VALUES(48,'Utrecht','Roelantdreef 41');
INSERT INTO product VALUES(20,'AH halfvolle melk',0.99);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(21,'AH pindakaas',2.39);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(22,'tandenborstel',1.35);

INSERT INTO transactie VALUES(456,'2019-12-01','17:35',65472335,35);
INSERT INTO aankoop VALUES(456,20,2);
INSERT INTO aankoop VALUES(456,21,1);
INSERT INTO aankoop VALUES(456,22,1);


INSERT INTO transactie VALUES(789,'2019-12-03','12:25',65472335,48);
INSERT INTO aankoop VALUES(789,20,1);
```

Comment: What is `aantal` ? You are using two tables in your query `aankoop, transactie` but where is the join ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: ```aantal``` in dutch means amount

Answer (score 0):

use `sum()` aggregate function

```
select sum(aantal) from Aankoop a join Transactie t on
   a.transactienummer=t.transactienummer
where product=20 and datum BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
```

Comment: that doesnt work i tried it it gives only 2 as output

Comment: @KilimanJaro, why don't you add some sample data of your tables in the question - it would be then easy to understand

Comment: look it up again pls

Comment: @KilimanJaro, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e9664fe8d897c8873a2603ce0adf875 - it'll work. When you are applying filiaalnummer = 35 that time it will return 2 since there is only one row with this condition

Comment: thanks that one worked. i also want column omschrijving before the sum result how can i do that. i also want to change the name of sum to totaal when performing the query

Answer (score 0):

I'm just isolating the relevant data for your query : `transactie` and `aankoop`:
If your DBMS supports `WITH` clauses: ...
There is only one `aankoop` entry with `product` equal to 20. It points to `transactienummer` 456. And it as an `aantal` of  20. `product`-s 21 and 22 also exist in the same `transactienummer` of 456. And , in `transactie` , you see that `filiaalnummer` is 35 in the row with `transactienummer` of 456. So either you get an `aantal` of 4 with the `filiaalnummer`-based filter, or an `aantal` of 2 with the `product`-based filter.

You'll need to make up your mind ... :-]]

```
WITH 
aankoop(transactienummer,product,aantal) AS (
          SELECT     456,     20,   2
UNION ALL SELECT     456,     21,   1
UNION ALL SELECT     456,     22,   1
)
,
transactie(transactienummer,datum     ,tijd         ,bonuskaarnummer,filiaalnummer) AS (
          SELECT 456,DATE '2019-12-01',TIME '17:35' ,65472335       ,35
UNION ALL SELECT 789,DATE '2019-12-03',TIME '12:25' ,65472335       ,48
)
SELECT 
  SUM(aantal) AS aantal
FROM Aankoop a
JOIN Transactie t ON a.transactienummer = t.transactienummer
WHERE filiaalnummer=35
  AND datum BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
```